# The multi-part identifier "INTran.bAccountID" could not be bound

Tags: acumatica

I have override the ResultRecords view in InventoryTranHistEnq to display the account name from BAccountID.

Here is the full code snippet:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable resultRecords()
        {
            int startRow = PXView.StartRow;
            int totalRows = 0;
            decimal? beginQty = null;

            if (PXView.MaximumRows == 1 && PXView.Searches != null && PXView.Searches.Length == 1)
            {
                InventoryTranHistEnqResult ither = new InventoryTranHistEnqResult();
                ither.GridLineNbr = (int?)PXView.Searches[0];
                ither = (InventoryTranHistEnqResult)Base.ResultRecords.Cache.Locate(ither);
                if (ither != null && ither.InventoryID != null)
                    return new List<object>() { ither };
            }

            Base.ResultRecords.Cache.Clear();
            List<object> list = Base.InternalResultRecords.View.Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters, new object[PXView.SortColumns.Length], PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, PXView.Filters, ref startRow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalRows);
            PXView.StartRow = 0;

            foreach (PXResult<InventoryTranHistEnqResult> item in list)
            {
                InventoryTranHistEnqResult it = (InventoryTranHistEnqResult)item;
                it.BegQty = beginQty = (beginQty ?? it.BegQty);
                decimal? QtyIn = it.QtyIn;
                decimal? QtyOut = it.QtyOut;
                beginQty += (QtyIn ?? 0m) - (QtyOut ?? 0m);
                it.EndQty = beginQty;
                var bAccountGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<BAccountEnq>();
                try
                {
                    if (it!=null && it.DocRefNbr != null && it.InventoryID != null)
                    {
                        INTran tran = PXSelectReadonly<INTran, Where<INTran.refNbr, Equal<Required<INTran.refNbr>>, And<INTran.inventoryID, Equal<Required<INTran.inventoryID>>>>>.Select(Base, it.DocRefNbr, it.InventoryID);
                        if (tran != null && tran.BAccountID != null)
                        {
                            BAccount data = PXSelectReadonly<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Required<BAccount.bAccountID>>>>.Select(Base, tran.BAccountID);
                            if (data != null)
                            {
                                Base.ResultRecords.Cache.SetValue(it, "UsrCustomerName", data.AcctName);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                Base.ResultRecords.Cache.SetStatus(it, PXEntryStatus.Held);

            }
            return list;
        }
```

When I debug the code, I can see that I can set the Account Name value from BAccount. But, then when page loads full I get the error saying 'The multi-part identifier "INTran.bAccountID" could not be bound.'

So, when I looked into the trace  I found out the issues were raised on 'Refresh' and 'Save' command. (I have had used PXSelect first then changed that to PXSelectReadonly thinking that would avoid the save.)

[image]

What is the issue here?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem resolved with the same code after I removed AccountID column from grid.